# What is the precise meaning of slice(-4, 4, 0.25)?

Tags: python, numpy, slice

In most Python tutorials, `slice` is described as a notation, such as myarray[1:] for the sub-array of myarray starting from the 2nd element.

Now I need to invoke `scipy.optimize.brute`  which needs a slice as an object in its arguments. Its  example code uses `slice(-4,4,0.25)`, which looks like `numpy.arange(-4,4,0.25)` to me.

Anyway, I cannot find documentation about slice as an object. What does `slice(-4,4,0.25)` represent exactly?

Comment: documentation on the slice object: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/slice.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) object which can be passed as an argument to an index, giving it the given slice parameters.

e.g.

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.arange(10) 
s = slice(2,7,2) 

print(a[s])
>>>[2  4  6]
```